# How do I hide my favorites from all views different screens in Odoo 16?

Tags: python, xpath, hide, favorites, odoo-16

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U3os.png)

I need to hide the items in the box marked in red, can I use Scss or do I have to write XPath?, please help me?, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the standard UI:

• Go to the Setting-App

• Click in the top menu on "Technicals..."

• In its dropdown menum, Click on "Server Action"

[image]

(url similar to: /web#action=8&model=ir.actions.server&view_type=list&menu_id=4&cids=1)

• and search for your action "Insert view in article" and open it

• Click on the Security tab

• and create a group to restrict its access (display)